# show specific column based on max(column) result MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called 'nilai' and here's the entire content

```
mysql> select * from nilai;
+------------+------+-----------------+-------+
| nim        | nama | matkul          | nilai |
+------------+------+-----------------+-------+
| 0911500101 | ADI  | ALGORITMA       |    90 |
| 0911500101 | ADI  | KALKULUS        |    65 |
| 0911500101 | ADI  | PBO             |    90 |
| 0911500101 | ADI  | PEMROGRAMAN WEB |    90 |
| 0911500101 | ADI  | PTI             |    75 |
| 0911500102 | IDA  | ALGORITMA       |    80 |
| 0911500102 | IDA  | KALKULUS        |    70 |
| 0911500102 | IDA  | PBO             |    80 |
| 0911500102 | IDA  | PEMROGRAMAN WEB |    85 |
| 0911500102 | IDA  | PTI             |    90 |
| 0911500103 | EDI  | ALGORITMA       |    85 |
| 0911500103 | EDI  | KALKULUS        |    60 |
| 0911500103 | EDI  | PBO             |    85 |
| 0911500103 | EDI  | PEMROGRAMAN WEB |    85 |
| 0911500103 | EDI  | PTI             |    88 |
| 0911500104 | INA  | ALGORITMA       |    75 |
| 0911500104 | INA  | KALKULUS        |    50 |
| 0911500104 | INA  | PBO             |    75 |
| 0911500104 | INA  | PEMROGRAMAN WEB |    80 |
| 0911500104 | INA  | PTI             |    72 |
| 0911500105 | ANI  | ALGORITMA       |    92 |
| 0911500105 | ANI  | KALKULUS        |    68 |
| 0911500105 | ANI  | PBO             |    80 |
| 0911500105 | ANI  | PEMROGRAMAN WEB |    92 |
| 0911500105 | ANI  | PTI             |    90 |
+------------+------+-----------------+-------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I wanted to show 'max(nilai)' and 'min(nilai)' for each 'matkul' (or in English, subjects), so I created a query like this and it worked perfectly :

```
mysql> select matkul, min(nilai), max(nilai) from nilai group by matkul;
+-----------------+------------+------------+
| matkul          | min(nilai) | max(nilai) |
+-----------------+------------+------------+
| ALGORITMA       |         75 |         92 |
| KALKULUS        |         50 |         70 |
| PBO             |         75 |         90 |
| PEMROGRAMAN WEB |         80 |         92 |
| PTI             |         72 |         90 |
+-----------------+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

But that query only showed max(nilai) and min(nilai) without showing whom max(nilai) and min(nilai) belong to so the final result will be like this

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+----------------+
| matkul          | min(nilai) | max(nilai) | min belongs to | max belongs to |
+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+----------------+
| ALGORITMA       |         75 |         92 |            INA |            ANI |
| KALKULUS        |         50 |         70 |            INA |            IDA |
| PBO             |         75 |         90 |            INA |            ADI |
| PEMROGRAMAN WEB |         80 |         92 |            INA |            ANI |
| PTI             |         72 |         90 |            INA |      ANI / IDA |
+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

So I make a lot of queries but no one has worked, two of those are :

```
mysql> select matkul, max(nilai), nama from nilai group by matkul;
+-----------------+------------+------+
| matkul          | max(nilai) | nama |
+-----------------+------------+------+
| ALGORITMA       |         92 | ADI  |
| KALKULUS        |         70 | ADI  |
| PBO             |         90 | ADI  |
| PEMROGRAMAN WEB |         92 | ADI  |
| PTI             |         90 | ADI  |
+-----------------+------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and this

```
mysql> select matkul, (select nama from nilai having max(nilai) as maxname), (select   
nama from nilai having min(nilai) as minname) from nilai group by matkul;

+-----------------+---------+---------+
| matkul          | maxname | minname |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
| ALGORITMA       | ADI     | ADI     |
| KALKULUS        | ADI     | ADI     |
| PBO             | ADI     | ADI     |
| PEMROGRAMAN WEB | ADI     | ADI     |
| PTI             | ADI     | ADI     |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

So how can I make it all works, please give me advice, thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I think the easiest way is with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select matkul, min(nilai), max(nilai),
       substring_index(group_concat(nama order by nilai asc), ',', 1) as min_nama,
       substring_index(group_concat(nama order by nilai desc), ',', 1) as max_nama
from nilai
group by matkul;
```

If you have many, many students with the same subject, then you might encounter problems with the length of the string.  Also, you only get one student name.

If this is a problem, you can use correlated subqueries or joins:

```
select matkul, min(nilai), max(nilai),
       (select nama from nilai n2 where n2.matkul = n.matkul order by nilai asc limit 1) as min_nama,
       (select nama from nilai n2 where n2.matkul = n.matkul order by nilai desc limit 1) as max_nama
from nilai n
group by matkul;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying my post. I admit that I haven't read about group_concat and substring_index before. Next time, I will search deep down before I ask.

Comment: where does n2 and n come from? they are undefined, aren't they?

Comment: @januaryananda . . . Those are table aliases and they are an important part of the SQL language.

Comment: as far as I know, subquery cannot result more than one row, and I think that is what happening in the second subquery

(select nama from nilai n2 where n2.matkul = n.matkul order by nilai desc) as max_nama

Comment: @januaryananda . . . Those should have had `limit 1` at the end.

Comment: the second query can be modified to return ties by adding `group_concat` and `group by` to the subqueries i.e. `select group_concat(nama) from nilai n2 where n2.matkul = n.matkul group by nilai order by nilai asc limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
| PTI             |         72 |         90 |            INA |      ANI / IDA |
```

It looks like you want to return multiple students when there are ties in `min belongs to` and `max belongs to`. You can achieve this by selecting from derived tables where each row contains a list of students per subject and score and joining those scores to your max/min scores.

```
select t1.matkul, t1.min_nilai, t1.max_nilai, 
       t2.min_belongs_to, t3.max_belongs_to
from (
    select matkul, min(nilai) min_nilai, max(nilai) max_nilai
    from nilai group by matkul
) t1 
join (
    select nilai, matkul, group_concat(nama) min_belongs_to 
    from nilai group by nilai, matkul
) t2 on t1.min_nilai = t2.nilai and t1.matkul = t2.matkul
join (
    select nilai, matkul, group_concat(nama) max_belongs_to 
    from nilai group by nilai, matkul
) t3 on t1.max_nilai = t3.nilai and t1.matkul = t3.matkul
```

Answer (score 0):

One way - if you want ties to show up, is splitting the query into a union of two queries - one for the min and one for the max - and an outer query to combine them;

```
SELECT matkul, MIN(nilai), MAX(nilai), MIN(nama_min), MAX(nama_max) FROM (
  SELECT matkul, nilai, null nama_min, GROUP_CONCAT(nama SEPARATOR ' / ') nama_max 
  FROM nilai n1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM nilai n2 WHERE n1.matkul = n2.matkul AND n1.nilai < n2.nilai
  )
  GROUP BY matkul
  UNION ALL
  SELECT matkul, nilai, GROUP_CONCAT(nama SEPARATOR ' / ') nama_min, null 
  FROM nilai n1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM nilai n2 WHERE n1.matkul = n2.matkul AND n1.nilai > n2.nilai
  )
  GROUP BY matkul
)z
GROUP BY matkul;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bef7f0/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
select matkul, min(nilai) nilaiMIN, max(nilai) naliMAX
,(select nama from nilai where nilai = (select min(nilai) from nilai  where matkul = n.matkul))         namaMIN
,(select nama from nilai where nilai = (select max(nilai) from nilai  where matkul = n.matkul)) namaMAX
 from nilai n group by matkul
```